# Swagger client codegen does not include optional methods

Tags: resttemplate, swagger-codegen, zuora

I am using swagger codegen ([on this Zoura swagger](https://www.zuora.com/wp-content/themes/zuora/yaml/swagger.yaml)) to create a Java/rest template client. I am using the swagger Gradle plugin:

```
id "org.hidetake.swagger.generator" version "2.11.0"
```

Here is the config for it:

```
{
  "library": "resttemplate",
  "dateLibrary": "java8",
  "hideGenerationTimestamp": true,
  "modelPackage": "zuora.model",
  "apiPackage": "zuora.api",
  "invokerPackage": "zuora",
  "clientPackage" : "zuora.client"
}
```

The client does get generated, however even though there are many optional fields they are not getting created as such and everything is required. Am I missing something?

Comment: As per the code generation doc "For all the unspecified options default values will be used." Try to add "configPackage" to your configuration
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/7601

Comment: Thanks @Rizwan, that looks to talk about the server. I am trying to create a client. All generated content is appropriately packaged.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue and solved it like this:

```
<configOptions>
     <fullJavaUtil>false</fullJavaUtil>
</configOptions>
```

If you look at the [code](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/resources/Java/api.mustache), you will find that the condition is inverted.